# Is there a way to implement video mini player as in youtube?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create an app in flutter that has functionality like youtube, play video, search videos. I need to implement and make the mini player active like in youtube in multiple screens like in library, subscriptions section. Is there any way to preserve the state of video while switching between different pages? In the image I have attached I am in subscriptions page but the mini player is still playing. Is there any way that this can be implemented in flutter. Any help??

[image]

I could play video from the internet by providing the url but when I have to navigate to new screen I could not implement the mini player.

Answer (score 1):

what you need to use is the [miniplayer](https://pub.dev/packages/miniplayer) package from pub.dev. Just use the basic version:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    YourApp(),
    Miniplayer(
      minHeight: 70,
      maxHeight: 370,
      builder: (height, percentage) {
        return Center(
          child: Text('$height, $percentage'),
        );
      },
    ),
  ],
),
```

You can create the exact replica of the Youtube miniplayer with this package.